# Using printf to print characters when all I have is a void pointer to the data

Tags: c++, pointers, printf

So I have a structure with a void pointer as member, which points to data. I know it's a bunch of chars and I know the size (another member).
I want to print it in a way like

```
for (in i = 0; i < str.size; i++)
  printf("%c", (char)str.data[i]);
```

This is wrong according to the compiler. I know I have to cas to tell printf the correct size but I dont know how to.
Any help is appreciated. And also, since I'm using c++, is there a more comfortable way maybe with `std::string`?

Answer (score 1):

*"I have a structure with a void pointer as member"*

```
data[i]
```

is equivalent to:

```
*(data + i)
```

and you can not do pointer arithmetic with a void pointer.

---

*"is there a more comfortable way maybe with `std::string`?"*

Of course there is:

```
char* cdata = static_cast<char*>(str.data);
std::string myStr(cdata, cdata + str.size);
std::cout << myStr;
```

note that this solution will also automatically null-terminate the string.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
char *array = static_cast<char *>(str.data);
for (in i = 0; i < str.size; i++)
  printf("%c", array[i]);
```

or with string:

```
std::string s(static_cast<char *>(str.data), str.size);
std::cout << s;
```

or make sure that the last char of str.data is '\0' and you cand print it like this:

```
char *array = static_cast<char *>(str.data);
printf("%s", array);
```

**EDIT**

string constructor modified to receive the size of the input array of chars

**EDIT2**

new method of printing

Comment: How does it know the size of ´str.data´?

Comment: I forgot the size of the string in the constructor, my bad